# How do I find out what is broken on this service in Debian?

Tags: python, apache2

I have a web-based service that uses Python & a command line tool that gets called by a wrapper (of some sort).

- **This is what the service SHOULD look like when status is checked:**

```
# systemctl status usmd
usmd.service - Western Digital Resource Manager Web Application HTTP server
  Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/usmd.service; static; vendor preset:
 enabled)
  Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-12-31 11:28:26 IST; 1h 18min ago
Main PID: 35459 (python3)
   Tasks: 7 (limit: 7372)
  CGroup: /system.slice/usmd.service
          |-- 2650 /bin/sh -c wdds /dev/sg2 show handles
          |-- 2651 wddcs /dev/sg2 show handles
          |--19819 /usr/bin/python3 /opt/usm/inbandmgmt/middleware/main.py
```

- **This is what the service looks like when I install it:**

```
# systemctl status usmd
● usmd.service - Western Digital Resource Manager Web Application HTTP server.
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/usmd.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-10-11 13:03:10 EDT; 7h ago
   Main PID: 1002 (python3)
      Tasks: 25 (limit: 38356)
     Memory: 172.5M
        CPU: 2h 37min 23.653s
     CGroup: /system.slice/usmd.service
             └─1002 /usr/bin/python3 /opt/usm/inbandmgmt/middleware/main.py

Oct 11 18:46:05 GA01WDRM-TST-SRV01 python3[1002]:     drive_handles = WDDCS.get_handles(serial, hba_index,True)
Oct 11 18:46:05 GA01WDRM-TST-SRV01 python3[1002]:                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Oct 11 18:46:05 GA01WDRM-TST-SRV01 python3[1002]:   File "/opt/usm/inbandmgmt/app/services/hal/wddcs_wrapper.py", line 557, in get_handles
Oct 11 18:46:05 GA01WDRM-TST-SRV01 python3[1002]:     slot_map = (list(map(get_slot_map,output)))
Oct 11 18:46:05 GA01WDRM-TST-SRV01 python3[1002]:                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Oct 11 18:46:05 GA01WDRM-TST-SRV01 python3[1002]:   File "/opt/usm/inbandmgmt/app/services/hal/wddcs_wrapper.py", line 447, in get_slot_map
Oct 11 18:46:05 GA01WDRM-TST-SRV01 python3[1002]:     if items[dev_index].startswith("/dev/") or items[dev_index].startswith("PD"):
Oct 11 18:46:05 GA01WDRM-TST-SRV01 python3[1002]:        ~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^
Oct 11 18:46:05 GA01WDRM-TST-SRV01 python3[1002]: IndexError: list index out of range
Oct 11 18:46:05 GA01WDRM-TST-SRV01 python3[1002]: 10.168.101.99 - - [11/Oct/2023:18:46:04 -0400] "POST /storage/driveinfo?hba_index=1&serial=USWSJ01219EZ0023 HTTP/1.1" 500 265 "https://10.168.101.129/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; W>
```

I'm mainly concerned with the tree at the bottom showing what processes should be running, but mine error out.

How do I diagnose this?

I can run these commands manually, but the service seems to not be able to.

Comment: Probably a permissions error. There's a specific `index out of range` error in the text you posted. What do you have access to that the code might not have access to if executed as a different user, or from a different directory?

Comment: So, I installed this web-app in a Debian 12 system, logged in as root.

Therefore, I can run anything and I tested that I can run these tools that the web app is calling from anywhere in the system.

The executables involved are:
Python3
WDDCS <- a Western Digital storage tool
WDCKit <- another Western Digital tool


How to I test this and determine what permissions apache2 is running these under?

How would I have avoided these permissions issues?
I figured using root work for installation, & the docs didn't mention any permissions to set.